# Bug or feature: Cannot link immutable file

Tags: linux, xattr

I had set the immutable attribute for a file that shouldn't be changed until it is deleted
(The file was a backup image of a virtual machine).
As it seems the file also cannot be hard-linked, i.e. it cannot be renamed.

Is that the way it should be?
Compared to a file lacking write permission, this behaves quite differently.
I couldn't find a manual page giving details.

In case it matters:
The filesystem where the problem was seen was OCFS2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature. See [`man chattr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chattr.1.html#ATTRIBUTES):

> A file with the 'i' attribute cannot be modified: it
> cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to
> this file, most of the file's metadata can not be
> modified, and the file can not be opened in write mode.
> Only the superuser or a process possessing the
> `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` capability can set or clear this
> attribute.

It is possible to have multiple immutable hard links to a given file: create the links first, then make one of them immutable; they will all become immutable.

Comment: Somehow I overlooked that when browsing the different manual pages.